# Asp.net session variables get mixed up

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, session, user-controls, session-variables

I have a user control that uses an `UpdatePanel`.  The controls is essentially a table with a `Button`.  When the user clicks the `Button`, a modal popup opens that allows them to select some value.  Data for the table (which uses a `Repeater` as its `DataSource`) is stored in a session variable between partial postbacks (when the `UpdatePanel` fires) as a list of objects.  Everything works fine if I have just one control but if I use this control in the same page more than once, the list of objects in the session variables get combined and are not separated for each control.  I thought this might be because the session variable names are not unique, so anywhere I call or use the variable, I do it like this:

```
Dim sessionName as string = Me.UniqueID & "_" & "userNotificationDS"
Session(sessionName) = myListOfObjects
```

But this has not changed the outcome.  Anyone know what I might be doing wrong here?  If you believe the full code would be helpful, let me know.

Control Server Code:

```
Protected Sub delete_click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    Dim btn As LinkButton = CType(sender, LinkButton)
    Dim ds As New List(Of myObject)
    sessionName = Me.UniqueID & "_" & "myDataSet"

    ds = Session(sessionName.ToString)

    Dim id As String = btn.CommandArgument

    ds.RemoveAll(Function(userNotification) userNotification.User.NetworkID.Equals(id))

    Session(sessionName.ToString) = ds


    bindData(ds)
End Sub


Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    sessionName = Me.UniqueID & "_" & "myDataSet"

    If (Session(sessionName.ToString) IsNot Nothing) Then
        bindData(Session(sessionName.ToString))
    End If
End Sub  

 Private Function buildPagedSet(ByVal userNotification As List(Of myObject)) As PagedDataSource
    Dim ps As PagedDataSource = New PagedDataSource()

    ps.DataSource = userNotification
    ps.AllowPaging = True
    ps.PageSize = numRows

    Return ps
End Function

  Public Sub bindData(ByVal commentList As List(Of myObject))
    sessionName = Me.UniqueID & "_" & "myDataSet"
    Dim currentPage As Integer = 0
    Dim ps As PagedDataSource
    Dim numLable As Label
    Dim denomLable As Label
    Dim curPage As Integer = 1
    Dim totalPage As Integer = 0

    If (Not myObject Is Nothing) Then

        Try
            ps = buildPagedSet(commentList)
            totalPage = ps.PageCount
            Session(sessionName.ToString) = commentList 
            rowTotal = ps.Count

            'for paging
            If Not (ViewState(Me.UniqueID & "_Page") Is Nothing) Then
                currentPage = Convert.ToInt32(ViewState(Me.UniqueID & "_Page"))
            Else
                ViewState(Me.UniqueID & "_Page") = 1
                currentPage = 1
            End If

            If (currentPage > 0 And currentPage <= ps.PageCount) Then
                ps.CurrentPageIndex = currentPage - 1
                Me.dataRepeateUsers.DataSource = ps
                Me.dataRepeateUsers.DataBind()

            ElseIf (currentPage >= ps.PageCount) Then
                ViewState(Me.UniqueID & "_Page") = Convert.ToInt32(ViewState(Me.UniqueID & "_Page")) - 1
            ElseIf (currentPage <= 0) Then
                ViewState(Me.UniqueID & "_Page") = Convert.ToInt32(ViewState(Me.UniqueID & "_Page")) + 1
            Else
            End If

        Catch ex As Exception
            Throw
        End Try
    Else
        Dim emptySet As New List(Of myObject)
        Me.dataRepeateUsers.DataSource = emptySet
        Me.dataRepeateUsers.DataBind()
    End If

End Sub
```

The control is instantiated like this:

```
Me.notifier1.bindData(notificationList)
```

In this example, when the user deletes something from notifier1 ( the delete_click event) the object is removed from the list and it gets added back to the session.  If anything causes notifier2's update panel to fire, it will display the same exact data as notifier1

Comment: I've also added break points to all these events.  When the code runs (ie the user deletes a record) it's fine.  I can see the session key and the dataset and that they match.  There is no confusion here.  It's only when the other controls update panel fires.  Then, in the OnLoad event I can see that both session keys are getting the same dataset

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My hunch is your are storing your `myListOfObjects` in the session but reusing that object somwhere and modifying it and storing it in the `Session` again with a different key.  It is probably still the same object being stored for both `Session` keys.

You can do a simple test by storing an object in the `Session` with two differnt keys.  Then pull it out using the first key and modify that object and don't reassign it back to the `Session` (not needed anyways).  Now pull the other object out from the second key and look at it.  It will match the modifications because the object is the same object just stored under two diffeent keys in the `Session`.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  while it is true that I modify the initial list of objects quite a bit (adding/editing/removing/reordering) in the list of myListOfObjects I always save it with a session ID like I posted above, using the user controls uniqueId.

Comment: @jason but the point I am saying is both unique keys are storing a reference to the same object. So you can do `Session["A"]` and `Session["B"]` but they both are storing the same reference so when you think you are dealing with the `A` version, you are actually using `B` as well.  Again this is just a hunch based on how you have described the problem.  Can you post how you store each `Session` object (showing you are using `new` objects) and how you are noticing that they are mixed together.

Comment: Yes, I will add the relevant code above.  I see what you are saying, but I have put break points on every event and at no time see what you describe happening.  I know that this is occurring because of this scenario: As I said, the control is a table with a datarepeater attached to it.  When the user click a button, they are presented with a dialog to select values.  These values get added (or removed) to the repeater.  When I make a change in one control its update panel fires and updates the table.  If an event causes the other table to refresh, the same change will appear there.

Answer (score 0):

If Kelsey's hunch is correct, you could store each of the instances of myListOfObjects in a `Dictionary(Of String, myListOfObjectsType)` and use the .UniqueID as the key (the Of String part).